# jQuery AppendChild With Images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append an image into a span, it works perfectly outputting the image path as text using:

```
homeTeamName_span.appendChild(homeTeamName_crest);
```

However, when trying to wrap image tags around it, it doesn't do anything and no data will load because of it.

What would be the reason for this?

```
homeTeamName_span.appendChild("<img src='homeTeamName_crest' />");
```

Function source

```
    window.onload = function() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://bushell.net/football/site/includes/webservice.php?service=allfixtures&limit=10&competition=427";
var url2 = "http://bushell.net/football/site/includes/webservice.php?service=allfixtures&limit=10&competition=426"

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        getECL(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function getECL(response) {
    var ECL_arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    //add 6hrs
    var ecl_games = document.getElementById("ecl-games");
    for(i = 0; i < ECL_arr.length; i++) {
        var gameInfo_container = document.createElement("LI");
        ecl_games.appendChild(gameInfo_container);

        var homeTeamName_span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        homeTeamName_span.className = "text-right";
        var homeTeamName_text = document.createTextNode(ECL_arr[i].homeTeamName);
        homeTeamName_span.appendChild(homeTeamName_text);
        gameInfo_container.appendChild(homeTeamName_span);

        var date_span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        date_span.className = "d-g";
        var date_span_text = document.createTextNode(ECL_arr[i].date);
        date_span.appendChild(date_span_text);
        gameInfo_container.appendChild(date_span);

        var awayTeamName_span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        awayTeamName_span.className = "text-left";
        var awayTeamName_text = document.createTextNode(ECL_arr[i].awayTeamName);
        awayTeamName_span.appendChild(awayTeamName_text);
        gameInfo_container.appendChild(awayTeamName_span);
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            getPrem(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url2, true);
    xmlhttp.send();     
function getPrem(response){
        var prem_arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var prem_games = document.getElementById("prem-games");
        for(var j = 0; j<prem_arr.length; j++) {
            var gameInfo_container = document.createElement("LI");
            prem_games.appendChild(gameInfo_container);

            var homeTeamName_span = document.createElement("SPAN");
            homeTeamName_span.className = "text-right";
            var homeTeamName_text = document.createTextNode(prem_arr[j].homeTeamName);
            var homeTeamName_crest = document.createTextNode(prem_arr[j].homeTeamCrest);
            homeTeamName_span.appendChild("<img src='homeTeamName_crest' />");
            homeTeamName_span.appendChild(homeTeamName_text);
            gameInfo_container.appendChild(homeTeamName_span);

            var date_span = document.createElement("SPAN");
            date_span.className = "d-g";
            var date_span_text = document.createTextNode(prem_arr[j].date);
            date_span.appendChild(date_span_text);
            gameInfo_container.appendChild(date_span);

            var awayTeamName_span = document.createElement("SPAN");
            awayTeamName_span.className = "text-left";
            var awayTeamName_text = document.createTextNode(prem_arr[j].awayTeamName);
            awayTeamName_span.appendChild(awayTeamName_text);
            gameInfo_container.appendChild(awayTeamName_span);
        }
        console.log("loop finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a jQuery tag, although I don't see what this has to do with jQuery. Although `appendChild` expects a Node element, you will want to create a element with `document.createElement()`, then use that as a paramater.

Comment: I have a feeling this is next to impossible to answer because we don't know what the value of `prem_arr[j].homeTeamName` or `prem_arr[j].homeTeamCrest` is. As in the answer provided by `Diptox`, part of the problem is this: `.appendChild("<img src='homeTeamName_crest' />");`. You're passing in the variable `homeTeamName_crest` as a string literal. What do you expect the value of `homeTeamName_crest` to be?

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to respond. I expect it to be a the image path, to which I can just wrap image tags around and display it as an image rather than text. Hopefully that makes sense. I also added a bit more of the code if that helps

Comment: can you just add this line `console.log(prem_arr);` after 

`var prem_arr = JSON.parse(response);` And share your result from `console window` of browser ?

Comment: do you really use jQuery? because all I see is plain JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

this shoud work , if homeTeamName_crest is the path of the picture

```
$(homeTeamName_span).append("<img src='"+homeTeamName_crest+"' />")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply - this puts the image source as 

path/[object%20Text]

Comment: added to the original post

Answer (score 0):

What if you do this?

```
var homeTeamName_crest = prem_arr[j].homeTeamCrest; // <--- change this line, don't make it a textNode
homeTeamName_span.appendChild("<img src='" + homeTeamName_crest + '/>"); // <--- change this line, we want to interpolate the string as the path to the image
```

Comment: hi, thanks for taking the time - but still same issue

Comment: what's the error? If you `console.log(homeTeamName_crest)`, does it print valid path to images?

Comment: yes valid image paths http://bushell.net/football/html/fiver_bushell.html